# How do I list all values in 3 different columns in a new column?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I have three seperate columns with values in an Excel Sheet. Now I want to create a new column that concatenates all values from these columns. When I add new values to one of these three columns, I want the summarized column to update automatically. How do I do this?

```
Table1

ColumnA  ColumnB  ColumnC
VALUE1   VALUE4   VALUE7
VALUE2   VALUE5   VALUE8
VALUE3   VALUE6   VALUE9
         VALUE10
```

Generated Result:

```
Table2

VALUE1
VALUE2
VALUE3
VALUE4
VALUE5
VALUE6
VALUE10
VALUE7
VALUE8
VALUE9
```

Comment: How can we answer this? I have no idea how you want to summarise the values... by occurrence? By those with a value greater or less than something? What type of new value would you want to add?

Comment: I just want a dull list of the values in the three columns. Nothing fancy. My problem is how it recongizes when I add a value to the first column so all the values from the second column move down so I don't have to change or add any formula.

Comment: I *think* you want to use `INDIRECT`

Comment: Sorry. Added an example hope it is more clear now.

Answer (score 1):

Enter the following *Event Macro* in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim inpt As Range, i As Long, K As Long, N As Long
    Dim j As Long

    Set inpt = Range("A:C")
    If Intersect(Target, inpt) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        Range("D:D").Clear
        K = 1
        For i = 1 To 3
            N = Cells(Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row
            For j = 1 To N
                Cells(K, 4).Value = Cells(j, i).Value
                K = K + 1
            Next j
        Next i
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

It will monitor changes to columns **A** through **C** and update column **D** accordingly.

[image]

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Comment: Great! How Would I have to modify the code to be able to access Tables in different other WorkSheets?

Comment: @BenediktDichgans  You would place a **similar** macro in each worksheet, *(adapting it to the details of that worksheet)*

Comment: Hm I have hoped for a solution without coding. Thanks you for your help though.

Answer (score 1):

I’ve got an answer that doesn’t require coding.

- I’ll assume that you want to put the combined (concatenated) list
  in Column `D` of the same sheet. 
  If you want it elsewhere, that’s a trivial change.
- My solution requires two “helper columns”;
  for example, Columns `E` and `F` on the same sheet. 
  If you want them elsewhere, that’s a trivial change.
- I assume that you will not be putting blanks
  in the first three columns (i.e., ***in*** the data, before the last value),
  and that you want those columns simply concatenated, and not sorted or deduped. 
  If I misunderstand, that’s a major change.
- I assume that every column has at least one value;
  i.e., that `A1`, `B1` and `C1` are non-blank. 
  If that assumption is not valid,
  this solution can (probably) be adapted for that.

---

### Solution:

- Enter `=IF(E1<0, "", OFFSET($A$1, F1, E1))` into cell `D1`.
- Drag/fill cell `D1` down into `D2`.
- Enter `0` into cells `E1` and `F1`.
- Enter
  `=IF(E1<0, E1, IF(OFFSET($A$1, F1+1, E1)<>"", E1, IF(E1<2, E1+1, -1)))`
  into cell `E2`.
- Enter `=IF(E1<0, 0, IF(OFFSET($A$1, F1+1, E1)<>"", F1+1, 0))` into cell `F2`.
- Select cells `D2:F2` and drag/fill down as far
  as you expect the combined list ever to be. 
  (Of course you can always extend it later.)

Columns `E` and `F` contain
the (0-based) column and row number of the value in Column `D`. 
For example, `0,0` is `A1`, `0,2` is `A3`, `1,3` is `B4`, etc. 
A negative value in Column `E` indicates that
you are beyond the end of the data. 
The formula in Column `D` evaluates to blank if the `E` value is negative;
otherwise, it uses the `OFFSET()` function to retrieve
the value indexed by the `E` and `F` numbers.

The formulas in Columns `E` and `F` check whether
the previous `E` value is negative,
and, if it is, set the next row to `-1,0` —
so, once you’re past the end of the list, you’re past it,
and you don’t start tying yourself into knots. 
Otherwise, if there is a next value in the current column,
we advance to that value (`E1,F1+1`). 
Otherwise, we go to the top of the next column —
except, if the current column is #2 (`C`),
we advance to column #-1, because we’re at the end.

[image: screenshot of spreadsheet]

You can now add and delete values in Columns `A`, `B` and `C`,
and the list in Column `D` will update automatically. 
Once you get this working, you can hide the helper columns.

Comment: I like your solution the only problem is the sortability.

Comment: Well, gosh, (1) the example in your question isn't sorted, and (2) Gary's Student's answer doesn't provide sorting, either. If sorting is an issue, [why didn't you say so?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2yfXgu37iyI&t=4m11s)

Comment: I'm sorry! I didn't know this was relevant for the solution...

Comment: A kid walks into a candy shop and asks for chocolate.  The shopkeeper shows him a box of chocolates, and the kid says, “That looks great.”  Then the shopkeeper says, “Too bad strawberries are out of season, so I don’t have any chocolate-covered strawberries.”  The kid (gesturing toward the box of chocolates) says, “Well, then, these are no good; I really wanted chocolate-covered strawberries.” … … … … … … …  Do you get the point?  You started wanting a feature only after you were told that it would be hard to obtain.